# Keeping New changes after Git Merge

Tags: git, git-merge

I tried to merge two branches and there were some files which were not auto-merged.
I have conflicts markers in non-merged files for eg:

`<<<<<< HEAD 
 int a=4;
 ===========
 int a=5; 
 <<<<<<< branch2`

If I always want to keep the changes from merged branch in my files i.e. everything below the
=======, Is there a command or script way to do it rather than manually editing each file?

Comment: Which one is *latest?* The conflict above means that in the base, someone chose to have `a` set to, say, 2. *I* claim the correct value is 4, you claim it is 5. If I made my claim today and you made yours yesterday, do you want to keep my claim in `HEAD`, or your claim in `branch2`?

Comment: If you always want your changes to override mine, you can use `-X ours` to prefer the commit Git calls "ours" (which in this case is yours from `branch2`). But what if mine is the right one?

Comment: Yes, basically I want all the changes in my file from the branch I am merging, so in this case my master branch had value of a=4, my branch which I have merged with master has value a=5, so I want to keep a=5.

Comment: FWIW, I generally consider keeping your changes and discarding the other changes a bad policy and highly discourage it among my development teams.  Chances are some of those changes are important and yours don't completely overlap.  Meaning that some of them need to be kept, and possibly provide a better answer than your solution.  Throwing away other people's work without understanding what has happened is a poor practice, IMO.  If this is you playing around, then that's okay. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have merge conflicts in multiple files and based on your decision to keep which file, you can use git commands

```
git merge master     
Auto-merged default.html
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in default.html
Auto-merged index.html
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in index.html
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

you can decide which files you have to keep, for example :

```
git checkout --theirs default.html
git checkout --ours index.html
```

Comment: Ensure you're aware about the changes your are disregarding and why.

Answer (score 4):

`git merge -X ours other_branch` will preserve your changes.

`git merge -X theirs other_branch` will do the opposite.

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_merge_strategies